# is this code transferring 1kb or in bits ? a little confused

Tags: java, networking, units-of-measurement

i have been trying to test network performance, but have a question

```
static public void main(String[] args) 
{
    MPI.Init(args);
    int myrank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
    int tag = 99;
    int maxlen = 104857600; 
    int minlen = 1; //1kb ?
    char [] sendbuff = new char [maxlen];
    char [] recvbuff = new char [maxlen];
    long speedKbps;
    long speedMbps;
    if (myrank == 0) 
    {
        for (int len = minlen; len <= maxlen; len *= 2) 
        { //len=*2 doubles the ping size each time
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();                  
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(sendbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recvbuff, 0, len, MPI.CHAR, 1, tag);
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("Time for the ping to be sent and recived of " + len + " kb is " + duration + " nanoseconds");
            double transferRate = (len/ duration ) ; //amount of data in kilobytes transferred in 1 second
            System.out.println("transferRate: " + transferRate + "KB per second");
        }
    }
}
```

The `minlen = 1`, what size is this, is it 1 KB, 1 bit, 1 byte?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're sending items from a character array, len in each iteration of the loop is the number of characters to send. So the size of minlen=1 is the size of 1 character, which in Java is 2 bytes.

[Source for the size of a  Java char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Ok thanks, so minlen is 2 bytes, what is the 'maxlen = 104857600;' in bytes ?

Comment: Since that's the maximum number of characters you're sending, just multiply it by the size of one character. 104857600 characters * 2 bytes per character = 209715200 bytes total, or 200 megabytes.

Answer (score 2):

As your send buffer used char as data type it's byte.

Comment: As his send buffer uses `char`, it would be `char`.